# Что быстрее использовать при заполнении? Map или 2 list'a

Tags: java, android

Привет, я добавляю в map 100 элементов, при этом у значений нет никакой закономерности. Работаю над приложением android и запуск длится 4-5 секунд. Возможно, это немного, но всё равно раздражает. Может быть, если использовать 2 листа, приложение будет быстрее запускаться? Сам бы проверил, но тут же 100 элементов.

Comment: Даже если вы сможете сэкономить время заменой типа коллекции, это будет время порядка микросекунд. Если ваше приложение запускается на реальном устройстве 4-5 секунд, причину надо искать в другом месте.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я пробовал уменьшить количество элементов этого же map'a до 5, при этом приложение запустилось мгновенно. Поэтому я думаю, что проблема именно в заполнении map'a

Comment: Действительно, я сэкономлю только несколько микросекунд. Тогда не знаю, что делать.

Comment: Профилировать код.

Comment: @Zeltam, Дело-то не в коллекции, а в подготовке объектов, которые Вы туда добавляете.

Comment: Решено, спасибо Вам, дело было, действительно, не в коллекции, нашёл другую причину)

Answer (score 0):

*Теоретически будет быстрей заполняться 2 List чем 1 Map.*

Давайте проверим.
Много условий, но давайте немного конкретизируем. Мы возьмем несинхронизированные коллекции и напишем локальный timeTest. Используем популярные коллекции, в интерфейсе List мы используем ArrayList, ну а из Map - HashMap. Для чистоты эксперимента работаем естественно в 1 потоке. Аргументом выступает Object String, итерацией будет Integer, он же value в Map. Для получения точных данных производилось 100 запусков, для 1000000 String-ов в каждой коллекции. Я покажу средние значения (секунды):

```
    --> LIST ave = 0,291091674
    --> HashMap ave = 0,292800937
    --> LISTx2 ave = 0,243387644
```

Итог: действительно разница даже для 1кк String очень мала. Поэтому причину необходимо скорей всего искать при создании объектов.